# Kafka manager configuration issue in kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera, confluent-platform, yahoo-kafka-manager

I was trying to install and configure kafka manager in my kafka cluster but facing issue while building kafka manager binary as below.

```
./sbt clean dist.
```

Server is not connected with internet so not able to download required binary and handing with error:

> getting scala version x.x.x

Kindly help to install and configure kafka manager offline.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run sbt in offline mode by setting below parameter:

```
$ sbt "set offline := true" run
```

And make sure you have all the required dependencies and components in the local .ivy cache `.ivy2/cache` in order to build the project offline.

Comment: in which file I need to set above parameter. Can you specify the config file?